# Winforms c# app on datagridview binding

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview

I have a `WinForms` application and would like to bind an XML file to a `DataGridView`. On the first 2 rows of the `DataGridView` I need to append a timespan (HH:MM) time format. How do I achieve this, so that in addition all the rows are editable? What would be the best way to display the data in the `DataGridView`.

```
DataColumn col1 = new DataColumn("value", typeof(string));
DataColumn col2 = new DataColumn("comment", typeof(string));
this.table.Columns.Add(col1);
this.table.Columns.Add(col2);
this.table.ReadXml(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "CFResource.xml");
table.Rows[0].Field<TimeSpan>("BhrFromTime").ToString(@"hh\:mm");
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.table;
```

My XML file looks as follows:

```
<root>
  <Time>
  <data name="BhrFromTime" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>08:00</value>
    <comment>Bhr start time</comment>
  </data>
  <data name="BhrToTime" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>19:00</value>
    <comment>bhr from time</comment>
  </data>
  </Time>
  <UserWarning>
  <data name="U0001" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>UW1</value>
    <comment>UserWarning 1</comment>
  </data>
  <data name="U0003" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>UW2</value>
    <comment>UserWarning 3</comment>
  </data>
  <data name="U0002" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>UW3</value>
    <comment>UserWarning 2</comment>
  </data>
  <data name="U0004" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>UW4</value>
    <comment>UserWarning 4</comment>
  </data>
  <data name="U0007" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>UW5</value>
    <comment>user warning 5</comment>
  </data>
  </UserWarning>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the easiest way is to load the xml file into a DataSet and in your case bind table `data` to the DataGridView:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml("xmlfile1.xml");
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["data"];
```

Which produces this:

[image]